# what is mean by current user model for this line of code. from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

Tags: django

I can't understand this line of code from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model. It tells that it takes the current user model. But what is meant by the current user model?

Comment: No it doesn't. Where did you read that?

Comment: then what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Django you have a default [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) that comes with the [authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/), it's referenced in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you can [write a custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) and override `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to reference your custom model.

If you check the source code for [get_user_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) you can see that all it does is return the model defined in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` or raise an exception if no model is defined.